# Node.js mocha testing: ReferenceError: session is not defined

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, session, mocha.js

I wrote mocha code for testing login and registration system:
Here is the code:
**`controllers/account.js`**

```
var AccountController = function(userModel, session, mailer) {

    this.crypto = require('crypto');
    this.uuid = require('node-uuid');
    this.ApiResponse = require('../models/api-response.js');
    this.ApiMessages = require('../models/api-messages.js');
    this.UserProfileModel = require('../models/user-profile.js');
    this.userModel = userModel;
    this.session = session;
    this.mailer = mailer;
};

module.exports = AccountController;

//gets the current session
AccountController.prototype.getSession = function() {
    return this.session;
};

//sets the current session
AccountController.prototype.setSession = function(session) {
    this.session = session;
};

//Creates cryptographically-strong pseudo random hash of the password
AccountController.prototype.hashPassword = function(password, salt, callback) {
    // we use pbkdf2 to hash and iterate 10k times by default 
    var iterations = 10000,
        keyLen = 64; // 64 bit.
    this.crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keyLen, callback);
};

//log in method
AccountController.prototype.logon = function(email, password, callback) {

    var me = this;

    me.userModel.findOne({
        email: email
    }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) {
            return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                success: false,
                extras: {
                    msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR
                }
            }));
        }

        if (user) {

            me.hashPassword(password, user.passwordSalt, function(err, passwordHash) {

                if (passwordHash == user.passwordHash) {

                    var userProfileModel = new me.UserProfileModel({
                        email: user.email,
                        firstName: user.firstName,
                        lastName: user.lastName
                    });

                    me.session.userProfileModel = userProfileModel;

                    return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                        success: true,
                        extras: {
                            userProfileModel: userProfileModel
                        }
                    }));
                } else {
                    return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                        success: false,
                        extras: {
                            msg: me.ApiMessages.INVALID_PWD
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        } else {
            return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                success: false,
                extras: {
                    msg: me.ApiMessages.EMAIL_NOT_FOUND
                }
            }));
        }

    });
};

//log off method
AccountController.prototype.logoff = function() {
    if (this.session.userProfileModel) delete this.session.userProfileModel;
    return;
};

//register method
AccountController.prototype.register = function(newUser, callback) {
    var me = this;
    me.userModel.findOne({
        email: newUser.email
    }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) {
            return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                success: false,
                extras: {
                    msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR
                }
            }));
        }

        if (user) {
            return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                success: false,
                extras: {
                    msg: me.ApiMessages.EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS
                }
            }));
        } else {

            newUser.save(function(err, user, numberAffected) {

                if (err) {
                    return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                        success: false,
                        extras: {
                            msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR
                        }
                    }));
                }

                if (numberAffected === 1) {

                    var userProfileModel = new me.UserProfileModel({
                        email: user.email,
                        firstName: user.firstName,
                        lastName: user.lastName
                    });

                    return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                        success: true,
                        extras: {
                            userProfileModel: userProfileModel
                        }
                    }));
                } else {
                    return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                        success: false,
                        extras: {
                            msg: me.ApiMessages.COULD_NOT_CREATE_USER
                        }
                    }));
                }

            });
        }

    });
};

//reset password method
AccountController.prototype.resetPassword = function(email, callback) {
    var me = this;
    me.userModel.findOne({
        email: email
    }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) {
            return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                success: false,
                extras: {
                    msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR
                }
            }));
        }

        // Save the user's email and a password reset hash in session. We will use
        var passwordResetHash = me.uuid.v4();
        me.session.passwordResetHash = passwordResetHash;
        me.session.emailWhoRequestedPasswordReset = email;

        me.mailer.sendPasswordResetHash(email, passwordResetHash);

        return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
            success: true,
            extras: {
                passwordResetHash: passwordResetHash
            }
        }));
    })
};

/*Users will invoke this method when they access a special web page using the “password reset” link 
inside the email that they will receive after they perform the first step of the password reset 
process*/
AccountController.prototype.resetPasswordFinal = function(email, newPassword, passwordResetHash, callback) {
    var me = this;
    if (!me.session || !me.session.passwordResetHash) {
        return callback(null, new me.ApiResponse({
            success: false,
            extras: {
                msg: me.ApiMessages.PASSWORD_RESET_EXPIRED
            }
        }));
    }

    if (me.session.passwordResetHash !== passwordResetHash) {
        return callback(null, new me.ApiResponse({
            success: false,
            extras: {
                msg: me.ApiMessages.PASSWORD_RESET_HASH_MISMATCH
            }
        }));
    }

    if (me.session.emailWhoRequestedPasswordReset !== email) {
        return callback(null, new me.ApiResponse({
            success: false,
            extras: {
                msg: me.ApiMessages.PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_MISMATCH
            }
        }));
    }

    var passwordSalt = this.uuid.v4();

    me.hashPassword(newPassword, passwordSalt, function(err, passwordHash) {

        me.userModel.update({
            email: email
        }, {
            passwordHash: passwordHash,
            passwordSalt: passwordSalt
        }, function(err, numberAffected, raw) {

            if (err) {
                return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                    success: false,
                    extras: {
                        msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR
                    }
                }));
            }

            if (numberAffected < 1) {

                return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                    success: false,
                    extras: {
                        msg: me.ApiMessages.COULD_NOT_RESET_PASSWORD
                    }
                }));
            } else {
                return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                    success: true,
                    extras: null
                }));
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**`test/user-mock.js`**

```
var UserMock = function () {

    this.uuid = require('node-uuid');
    this.crypto = require('crypto');
    this.User = require('../models/user.js');
    this.seedUsersCount = 10;
    this.users = [];
    this.err = false;
    this.numberAffected = 0;
};

UserMock.prototype.setError = function (err) {
    this.err = err;
};

UserMock.prototype.setNumberAffected = function (number) {
    this.numberAffected = number;
};

UserMock.prototype.seedUsers = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.seedUsersCount; i++) {

        var passwordSaltIn = this.uuid.v4(),
            cryptoIterations = 10000, // Must match iterations used in controller#hashPassword.
            cryptoKeyLen = 64,       // Must match keyLen used in controller#hashPassword.
            passwordHashIn;

        var user = new this.User({
            email: 'Test' + i + '@test.com',
            firstName: 'FirstName' + i,
            lastName: 'LastName' + i,
            passwordHash: this.crypto.pbkdf2Sync('Password' + i, passwordSaltIn, cryptoIterations, cryptoKeyLen),
            passwordSalt: passwordSaltIn
        });

        this.users.push(user);
    }
};

UserMock.prototype.getTestUser = function () {
    return this.users ? this.users[0] : null;
};

UserMock.prototype.findById = function (id, callback) {

    for (var i = 0, length = this.users.length; i < length; i++) {

        if (this.users[i]._id === id) {
            return callback(this.err, this.users[i]);
        }
    }        

    return callback(this.err, null);
};

UserMock.prototype.findOne = function (where, callback) {

    for (var i = 0, length = this.users.length; i < length; i++) {

        if (this.users[i].email === where.email) {
            return callback(this.err, this.users[i]);
        }
    }

    return callback(this.err, null);
};

UserMock.prototype.save = function (callback) {
    return callback(this.err, this, this.numberAffected);
};

module.exports = UserMock;
```

**`test/mailer-mock.js`**

```
var MailerMock = function () {  };

MailerMock.prototype.sendPasswordResetHash = function (email, passwordResetHash) { };

module.exports = MailerMock;
```

**`test/accounnt-controller-test.js`**

```
var AccountController = require('../controllers/account.js'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    should = require('should'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    User = require('../models/user.js'),
    UserMock = require('./user-mock.js'),
    MailerMock = require('./mailer-mock.js'),
    ApiMessages = require('../models/api-messages.js');


describe('AccountController', function() {
    var controller,
        seedUsersCount = 10,
        testUser,
        userModelMock,
        session = {},
        mailMock;
});

beforeEach(function(done) {
    userModelMock = new UserMock();
    mailerMock = new MailerMock();
    controller = new AccountController(userModelMock, session, mailerMock);
    done();
});


afterEach(function(done) {
    userModelMock.setError(false);
    done();
});

it('Returns db error', function(done) {

    userModelMock.setError(true);
    userModelMock.seedUsers();
    var testUser = userModelMock.getTestUser(),
        testUserPassword = 'Password0';

    controller.logon(testUser.email, testUserPassword, function(err, apiResponse) {

        should(apiResponse.success).equal(false);
        should(apiResponse.extras.msg).equal(ApiMessages.DB_ERROR);
        done();
    });
});


/*logon method*/
AccountController.prototype.logon = function(email, password, callback) {

    var me = this;

    me.userModel.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {

        if (err) {
            return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR } }));
        }

        if (user) {

            me.hashPassword(password, user.passwordSalt, function (err, passwordHash) {

                if (passwordHash == user.passwordHash) {

                    var userProfileModel = new me.UserProfileModel({
                        email: user.email,
                        firstName: user.firstName,
                        lastName: user.lastName
                    });

                    me.session.userProfileModel = userProfileModel;

                    return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                        success: true, extras: {
                            userProfileModel:userProfileModel
                        }
                    }));
                } else {
                    return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.INVALID_PWD } }));
                }
            });
        } else {
            return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.EMAIL_NOT_FOUND } }));
        }

    });
};
```

When I run `mocha` in terminal, I get the following error:

```
1) "before each" hook for "Returns db error"

0 passing (37ms)
1 failing

1)  "before each" hook for "Returns db error":
   ReferenceError: session is not defined
    at Context.<anonymous> (D:\PhoneGap_Projects\login\www\server\test\account-controller-test.js:24:55)
    at callFnAsync (C:\Users\Ajay Kulkarni-enEXL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:338:8)
    at Hook.Runnable.run (C:\Users\Ajay Kulkarni-enEXL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:290:7)
    at next (C:\Users\Ajay Kulkarni-enEXL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:298:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Ajay Kulkarni-enEXL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session object is local in scope to the defined test. Because mocha is calling the session object in the before each it is expecting session to be defined globally.

In simplest terms move the `var session = {}` outside of your `define('AccountController')` test